# Проблемы с моделью базы данных C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, такая проблема. Модель создавал с подходом Database First, предварительно сделав её в SQ Server Express, в соседних проектах все работает. Причем с некоторым контекстом в этом приложении он все таки работает, например, если заблокировать эти две строки, то ошибка появится только в методе Sorter.Sort(), хотя в Pareser.getNewArticles() тоже есть работа с контекстом.

Строка подключения в App.Config в порядке

Исключение:
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Сообщение = Нельзя проверить модель на совместимость, поскольку база данных не содержит метаданные модели. Проверить модель на совместимость можно только для баз данных, созданных с помощью Code First или Code First Migrations.
  Источник = EntityFramework
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   в RSS3.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\Anger\source\repos\RSS3\RSS3\Program.cs:строка 16

Comment: Может [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064692/312041) поможет

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!